# how to display data from the database into jsp

Tags: java, jsp

I have some values in list which  I want to compare it with the values stored in database  when I fetch the data from the database during its while loop I use for loop for getting the list values 
but after that my database data won't show any more if I remove the code of for loop, db data shown where I am doing wrong please help

```
<%
  try{
      String emi=request.getParameter("emi");
      imei=emi;
      String month=request.getParameter("month");
      String day=request.getParameter("dt");
      String year=request.getParameter("year");
      String month1=request.getParameter("month1");
      String day1=request.getParameter("dt1");
      String year1=request.getParameter("year1");
      String date =month+" "+day+" "+year;
      String date1=month1+" "+day1+" "+year1;
      System.out.println(date);
      System.out.println(date1);

      Connection con = history.show.getConnection();
      PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement("select * from sms where  s_imei='"+emi+"' and  sms_date between '"+date+"' and '"+date1+"'");


      ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
      officialNumber num=new officialNumber();
      ofcNumbers=num.checkNumber();

      System.out.println("List size" +ofcNumbers.size());

      while(rs.next())
      {
        for(int i=0;i<=ofcNumbers.size();i++)
        {
          String n = ofcNumbers.get(i);
        }                
%>

<tr>
   <td>                
     <%= rs.getString("sms_phoneNumber")%>
   <td>
     <%= rs.getString("sms_personName")%>
   <td>
     <%= rs.getString("sms_type")%>
   <td>
     <%= rs.getString("sms_date")%>
   <td>
     <%= rs.getString("sms_Time")%>
   <td>
     <%= rs.getString("s_logType")%>
</tr>    
<tr class="alt" >
    <td class="alt" colspan="6" >
      <%= rs.getString("sms_body")%>
      <% 
          }  //end of while        
        } //end of try
        catch(Exception e){}
      %>
```

officialNumber class is just for filling the list with the data

```
public class officialNumber {
   List<String> ofcNumbers= new ArrayList<String>();
   String listNumber;
  //  Connection con1 = history.show.getConnection();

    public List checkNumber()
    {
        Connection con = null;
     PreparedStatement ps = null;

     try
     {
      con = getConnection();
      ps = con.prepareStatement("select * from ofcNumbers");

      ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
System.out.println("before while loop") ;
      while ( rs.next())
      {
         System.out.println("after while loop") ;
           listNumber=rs.getString("phone_number");
           ofcNumbers.add(listNumber);
           System.out.println("first list size"+ofcNumbers.size()) ;

      }
 rs.close();
 ps.close();
 con.close();
     }
     catch(Exception ex)
     {
         System.out.println( ex.getMessage());
     }
     finally
     {


       //clean(con,ps);
     }
     return ofcNumbers;
    }

}
```

Comment: Your question is unclear. What is the officialNumber class?
Also that for loop has nothing to do with your result set.

Comment: You could start by closing all your `<td>` and `<tr>` tags.  Also, you are eating up any exception thrown so you'll never know if it is failing or why.

Comment: instead of consuming the excepion `catch(Exception e){}` try to reproduce `catch(Exception e){ e.printStackTrace();}` it and post the stacktrace

Comment: i want to match the table data with the in the list but first i am checking that the data of the list displayed or not on the console..data of list is displayed but my database data stop showing on the jsp page if does not happen then i wil match the list value with  this  <%= rs.getString("sms_phoneNumber")%> value

Comment: i just added the officialNumber class this class only fills the list with data which i want to campare it to my database values

Comment: @ M.Sharma  i found the exception thanks for the help